# How to get data from escaping closure into UICollectionview?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I'm downloading data from an S3 bucket to populate a UIcollectionview table. I know I have to use an escaping closure to use the data, but I still can't get the data into my collection view. In the code below my cell count still returns 0 instead of the number the actual number of files, which is 2. How do I get the data into the UIcollectionview code? Code below:

```
func listFiles(completionHandler: @escaping (Array<String>) -> ()){
    
    var audioFileArray: [String] = []
    
    resultSink = Amplify.Storage.list()
        .resultPublisher
        .sink {
            if case let .failure(storageError) = $0 {
                print("Failed: \(storageError.errorDescription). \(storageError.recoverySuggestion)")
            }
        }
        
        receiveValue: { listResult in
            
            print("Completed")
            
            listResult.items.forEach { item in
                
                audioFileArray.append(item.key)
            }
            
            for audio in audioFileArray{
                
                self.dowloadAudioFileName(audioFiles: audio)
            }
            
            completionHandler(audioFileArray)
            
    
            print("The audio files are: \(audioFileArray)")
            
        }
    
    self.soundBoardView.reloadData()
}


var globalAudioFileArray: [String] = []

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    listFiles(){ (audioFileArray) in

        self.globalAudioFileArray = audioFileArray
    }
    return globalAudioFileArray.count
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are getting datas on numberOfItemsIn section func?
Also you need to reload collection view when you set the array not end of the list files function.

You should get them in seperate func like below and you can call it in viewDidLoad;

```
func getData() {
    listFiles(){ (audioFileArray) in

    self.globalAudioFileArray = audioFileArray
self.soundBoardView.reloadData()
}

 }
```

Comment: I used the code you suggested in viewDidLoad, but I get a warning the collectionview.reloadData must only be used from the main thread, and also the data count is still zero. Is there a different place to reload the data?

Comment: You can wrap the colletionView.reloadData to DispatchQueue.main. Also are you sure about reloading collection view in the closure?

Comment: I'm not sure, but wrapping reloadData iDispatchQuee.main.async worked. Thanks for your help!